# How to create mirror image of textview in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a mirror image of textview in android. I tried the below code, but its not working

My code is as below:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
ImageView myImageView;
Bitmap bmp;
int bmpWidth, bmpHeight;

Matrix matrixMirrorY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        tv.buildDrawingCache();
        bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
        matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); 
        Bitmap mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, false);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(mirroredBitmap);          
            }       

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
ImageView myImageView;
Bitmap bmp;
int bmpWidth, bmpHeight;

Matrix matrixMirrorY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        myImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        tv.buildDrawingCache();
        bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
        matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); 
        Bitmap mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, false);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(mirroredBitmap);          
            }       

    }
```